# Application failed codesign verification. (Flash developed Iphone App)

Tags: ios, flash, codesign

I've developed my first App with Flash CS6 and not with Xcode. the App was tested on actual Iphone 4, 4s and 5 devices. it's bug free and ready for distribution. I've created both distribution certificate and provisioning profile. Both are applied in the publish setting in Flash CS6 and made sure in the deployment I've selected Deploy for App Store. now to upload the App to the app store i've already did all what is needed to be done in Itunes Connect and the status over there is "waiting for upload". to upload the app I'm using the Application Uploader that's included in the package of Xcode. So I've created the required Archive.zip and proceeded to the upload and get the following error:

**Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.**

what did I miss? Please help! thanks :)

Comment: You need to look at the Apple development site and look for the examples on uploading your application, and follow them to the letter. Your error message is generic, and it sounds like you need a valid distribution certificate (perhaps you're uploading an app with the developer certificate?)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comment. I've actually found the solution that might help others in this situation. here are the steps that i've done:

I went to Xcode and created a fake project. it automatically generates a .plist file and i've erased the content and replaced it with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>5GJX4765WZ.com.bobjt.largeimagesupport</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>5GJX4765WZ.com.bobjt.largeimagesupport</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Next I've opened the terminal and used this commanded to replace the old .plist that flash created with the new one:

```
codesign -f -s <your code signing identity> --resource-rules ./Payload/MySampleApp.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements ./MyEntitlements.plist ./Payload/MySampleApp.app
```

at this point it should replace it and if by any chance you encountered an error that states invalid file format... Make sure to download the latest Xcode and type this command :

```
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate"
```

and that's it :) cheers to all